# Reading multiline files in Apache beam separated with custom delimiters

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have  a text file separated by two delimiters(@*) and one of the field  contains multiline statements. ex:

```
     test@*123@*"contain
     multiline"
     test@*321@*"contain
     multiline"
```

Those are actual 2 rows but in text file it's 4 lines. The way I was trying is to retrieve the files with FileIO and then using pardo to open the file , find the last character in a line and if it's not ending with " then find the next line and append it with 1st line. my concern is beam processes the file in bundles .So if 2 lines are not in the same bundle then it will fail.

is my understanding correct ? and pls let me know the best way to handle the same.

[image]

Comment: Bundles are when you use windowing. Else everything is in a Global window. Plus using a mapper will consider each record separately.

Comment: Can we assume that all rows end with `"\n` ? If yes then try to use as a delimiter.

Comment: @Mr.Batra No, all `DoFn`s process input data in bundles despite what kind of Windows is used.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanenko Added a sample screenshot.  Here the 1st row will be of 2 lines The 1st line will end with "\n" after "good" and the 2nd after "late".

Comment: @alrou Thanks! Did you try to use `TextIO` with `"\n` as a delimiter?

Comment: An option of last resort is to use FileIO.match and then read the entire contents in a subsequent DoFn, splitting things up manually. This won't allow for sub-file sharding but may be sufficient if you have enough files (and/or follow it with a Reshuffle to redistribute expensive work). https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.30.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html